# Sentence joined by comma- Is it compound/complex

Tags: types-of-sentences

i have a sentence

> Dogs bark,crows crow but lions roar.

Is it compound, complex or compound-complex...I think its compound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question of whether a sentence is simple, compound or complex is whether it has a single clause, multiple independent clauses, or an independent clause and some dependent subordinate clauses.

There are three complete independent clauses here, "Dogs bark." "Crows crow." and "Lions roar".  They are linked by a coordinating conjunction "but". There are no subordinate clauses.